# Hard refresh automatically when the PHP page Loads up

Tags: php

I have a php file and it doesn't update the right data from the server(apache) the first time I open it. I have to do a hard refresh ( Shift + refresh ) or (ctrl + f5) for the right data to appear in the browser. After I use hard refresh, everything works perfectly and i don't have to do a hard refresh again for the data to come in. I have tried different codes from stack overflow to clear the cache, but it couldn't give me a right result.
So i wanted to know if there was a PHP function to do a hard refresh the first time i open the webpage so that my webpage works smoothly.

GOAL : Hard refresh automatically when the PHP page Loads up

code that my php file has at the moment

```
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
header("Pragma: no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
header("Expires: 0");
```

i have also tried

```
header("Expires: Tue, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT");
header("Last-Modified: " . gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s") . " GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, max-age=0");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

Comment: PHP doesn't know when the page is loaded. It only knows when it is done sending the content. If you are having such caching issues you need to check your browser settings and server settings. Try testing with different browsers and computers and see what results you get as this is not normal behavior.

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough code to determine your issue. Are you setting a `$_COOKIE` that you are testing against when the page loads?

Comment: Hey @StackSlave no, the code posted above are just the headers i used in my php file so that it will clear the cache. It has no relation with the code. Thanks